# VS Code Source Control is tracking all my files

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, version-control

I cloned a couple of repositories from Github, but now every time a make a new file, my Source Control tracks it and wants to send it to Github. I only want it to track the files I cloned from Github.

Also, every time I load a Python file, I have to choose a Python Interpreter. How do I get it to choose automatically? I only have one Python anyway.

[image]

Comment: don't work in the cloned repository

Comment: @rioV8 I don't think I am, these are a bunch of files from different folders.

Answer (score 1):

You can add them to .gitignore file.

If you'd like to set up a default interpreter for your applications, you can add an entry for `python.pythonPath` [manually inside your User Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment).